# C# settings being loaded from .exe.config but are saved to user.config

Tags: c#, settings.settings

For some reason when my application loads it reads the settings from programname.exe.config in the application path, but when I call Properties.Settings.Default.Save() the settings are saved in Appdata/local/program/version/user.config
**How do I get my application to load from user.config?**

If I delete programname.exe.config, its regenerated next time the program is run.

[image: settings]

[image: programname.exe.config and user.config]

Comment: The default behaviour is just what you described. User settings get a default value in the `<application>.config` file (in the ùserSettings` section), but then get written to `user.config`. When you read them again, they get read from `user.config` if it exists, or from `<application>.config` if it doesn't. I don't know why `user.config` is not being loaded for you, but the rest is just normal behaviour

Comment: Have you purposedly removed the `configSections/SectionGroup` xml from `user.config` for the screenshot?

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: @regularjoe - Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but read my update....

Answer (score 1):

This is the legitimate behavior. The `User` settings are specific to user, and therefore saved in user profile. Imagine where a user customize some setting for him, and they are being overridden by some other user. It will not be a good user experience certainly.

The loading of user settings would be same.

For  example you have a `UserSetting` called `quality`, you can read this setting like -

```
var qualitySettingValue = Properties.Settings.Default.quality;
```

...and you can modify this value and save the new settings like -

```
Properties.Settings.Default["quality"] = "New Quality Settings";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Now next time when you read this value like this -

```
var qualitySettingValue = Properties.Settings.Default.quality;
```

qualitySettingValue  will have the updated value -

`Application` level settings on the other hand are common to all users, will be saved in `Application.exce.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this,

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()
```

before the save.

Comment: Just a reminder - if you are debugging in VS, config file will get overwritten each time you do a build. Updated settings won't be preserved between runs of the application.